# CI Spark Ion_auth & phpactiverecord

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord, ion-auth

before anything, please understand i'm a complete codeigniter noob, and know only enough php to get by. But understand it really well if it's explained very well.

I'm building a web app, installed sparks, then ion_auth which is up and running correctly.

Users can sign up, yada yada yada.

Now i'm trying to create my first model which is 'project'.

This is where I get lost...

here is my Project Model, I want to use php-activerecord and have relationships between my users and projects.

```
class Project extends ActiveRecord\Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('user')
    );

    public function projects() {}
}
```

Since Ion_Auth is a spark and sitting in

```
-sparks
--ion_auth
---2.3.2
----models
-----ion_auth_model.php
```

here is the code for the top of that class

```
class Ion_auth_model extends CI_Model {
```

But when I change 'extends CI_Model' to the 'extends Activerecord\model' everything breaks.

how do I get this working so that I can have $has_many and $belongs_to in the appropriate models?

been on this for a couple of hours now and its finally starting to get to me..

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Why are you extending your project model from ActiveRecord\Model

Comment: so that I can use activerecord on the model. Instead of $this->project_model->get_projects();

I'll be able to do $data['projects'] = Project::find('all');

Answer (score 1):

As per the Codeigniter's Model [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) your model should extend CI_Model, load active record in your model like `$this->load->database();` or add in autoload and use it like  `$this->db->query('select * from tablename');`